# Default Phone Dialer

Tags: default-applications

I use Samsung Galaxy S2, Currently running on 4.1.2 JellyBean. I have downloaded an App called, 'Espier Dialer iOS 7' and I want that to be my default Dialer. I tried to goto Application Manager > Clear Defaults for Phone and tried to make this app my Default Dialer application, but the selection only shows 'Phone' and 'Skype' Any help guys?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to clear the defaults of any application.

If you install a new application that handles an intent for which you've already set a default, Android will "clear" that default so that the next time you fire the intent (e.g., dialing the phone) you will be prompted with the "choose an app to perform this action" menu.

It sounds to me like the app you've installed doesn't handle that intent, and that for you to use it you will need to explicitly launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to make you guys take a big trouble to try to solve my problem, I have now sorted out this problem by downloading Espier Launcher 7 and now the Dialer works as a plugin and all is set. Thank you for your valuable and precious time, guys!